# Why does main-bower-files filter some packages?

Tags: gulp, bower

I've got a gulp task which is intended to copy bower dependencies to another folder, but only a subset of the dependencies are being matched.

Here's a simplified version of the task which just prints out the matching paths:

```
gulp.task('list-dependencies',function() {
  gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*'), { base: './bower_components' })
    .pipe($.print());
});
```

Here's the bower.json file contents:

```
bower.json

    {
      "name": "app",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "3.0.0",
        "jquery": "1.10.2",
        "modernizr": "~2.8.3",
        "angular": "~1.4.4",
        "angular-ui": "~0.4.0",
        "angular-route": "~1.4.4"
      }
    }
```

Here's a listing of the bower_components folder:

```
$ ls bower_components/
angular  angular-route  angular-ui  bootstrap  jquery  modernizr
```

outut:

```
[13:30:08] Starting 'list-dependencies'...
[13:30:08] Finished 'list-dependencies' after 27 ms
[gulp] bower_components\jquery\jquery.js
[gulp] bower_components\angular\angular.js
[gulp] bower_components\angular-route\angular-route.js
[gulp] bower_components\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js
[gulp] bower_components\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css
```

As you can see, angular-ui and modernizr aren't listed.  Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bower has a concept of defining "main" files within a bower.json.  The packages that were missed were due to the fact that these packages didn't contain a bower.json file which defined the main files.  To get the main-bower-files plugin to work, you have to [define override](https://roots.io/using-bootstrap-with-bower-how-to-override-bower-packages/)s either within your bower file or as a parameter to main-bower-files.